# Selenium webdriver - How to locate the dropdown select element with first part is dynamic and second part is static

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

The ID is dynamic - first part is dynamic and second part is static

[Example element code]

```
<div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" id="abc123-0">
<div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" id="abc123-1">
<div class="ng-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" id="abc123-2">
```

`abc123` is dynamic and `-0`, `-1`, `-2` is static

Not able to capture the value in drop-down

I have tried below:

`//div[contains(@id,'-2')]` -  Not working

`//div[ends-with(@id,'-2')]` -  Not working

Comment: `//div[contains(@id,'-2')]` should work.
what happens if you use that?

Answer (score 1):

`//div[ends-with(@id,'-2')]` `ends-with` is not XPath 1.0

`//div[contains(@id,'-2')]` will not work if :

1. Your result expects only one element and there are besides `id="abc123-2"` also is's like `id="abc123-21"`
2. the random string `abc123` also contains a `-2`

If random string `abc123` does **not contain a dash** you could use this XPath:

`//div[substring-after(@id,'-')='2']`

The best option is to use this `XPath 1.0` alternative for `ends-with`:

```
//div[@id[substring(.,string-length(.) - string-length('2') + 1) = '2']]
```

where in this case `2` is the static part you want to use that as a variable when you compose your XPath